# Making a generic linked list implementation that can be used with different sized structs

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi I am currently working on a project where I am creating a very simple filesystem and I am working on some inode and general file cache implementations and I was wondering considering structs like this:

```
typedef struct disk_inode {
  short type; /* file type */
  short nlinks; /* number of directory entries referring to this file
  int size;    /* file size in bytes */
  short inode_indir_idx;
  /* pointers to the first NDIRECT blocks */
  blknum_t direct[INODE_NDIRECT];
  blknum_t indirect; /* The rest of the blocks */ 
}disk_inode_t;


struct cache{
    short blocknr;
    char block[512];
};
```

is there a way to create a generic list which can be used by both of these structures? This is in C and I cannot use any standard c libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic linked list which would take a `void *` as its element. Such implementation would require you to allocate your element in most cases though.

Here is a symple example:

```
typedef struct list_s
{
    void *elm;
    struct list_s *next;
    struct list_s *prev;
} list_t;

typedef struct
{
    int elem1;
    int elem2;
    int elem3;
} my_struct_t;

int main(void)
{
    my_struct_t *elem = malloc(sizeof(my_struct_t));
    list_t *list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));

    list->prev = NULL;
    list->next = NULL;
    list->elm = elem;
    return 0;
}
```